# Why does this indicate a phonon?

Tags: notation, phonons

In the very cool LaTeX package [svrsymbols](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/fonts/svrsymbols/svrsymbols.pdf), the authors associate a phonon with the following symbol:

[image]

Why is this iconography appropriate for a phonon?

Answer (score 1):

Although the [documentation](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/fonts/svrsymbols/svrsymbols.pdf) doesn't explicitly mention the reasoning, it does mention:

"the SVRsymbols font contain some new ideograms for use in Physics. The symbols have been designed so to be intuitive, easy to identify and to remember."

So we can try to piece together how this symbol is intuitive and easy to remember.  Since phonons are often represented in feynman diagrams as squiggles, it seems that the authors just replaced the standard bars on the "F" with those squiggles.  F for "phonon" it seems.  What about the photon?  I looks like they did more or less the same, but with a lowercase "f".  Notice  the similarity with the symbol for \polaron, \plasmon, and \polariton.

Although I am still confused by their choice for \boson . . .

Comment: It looks like a pair of wings flying over a degree symbol!

Comment: yea, its consistent with \boseDistrib : \boson  :: \fermiDistrib : \fermion but in what way does the wing symbol remind of a bose distribution?

Comment: Maybe they're a key component in the mechanics behind how Red Bull gives you wings?